# Why does an empty String returns false when comparing to boolean in ruby?

Tags: ruby

It might be a dumb question, but can someone please explain this:

```rb
if ""
  true
else
  false
end
=> true (OK)
```

```rb
!!("")
=> true (OK)
```

```rb
"" === true
=> false (OK)
```

```rb
"" == true
=> false (But why?)
```

Have a nice day!

Comment: Why do you think that `"" === true #=> false` is okay/expected but `"" == true #=> false` is not?

Comment: @Stefan Because I thought the "strict" operator would behave the same as in other languages. So that it also checks the data type. So String is not equal to Boolean

Comment: Simply because `""` and `true` are objects of different classes. If you convert your string into a boolean (i.e. `!!("") == true`), this will evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic concept of this question is a deep misunderstanding of Ruby operators. Here's the short of it - there's no such thing as operators in Ruby! All this `!`, `=`, `==` and `===` that you throw around - these are not operators.

So what's going on?

Ruby is an object oriented language (a real one, not like that fake Java and JavaScript things) and all these fancy character sequences you think of as operators are actually method calls on the object in their left:

- `==` method usually checks for equality - is the object on the right equal in content.
- `===` method is not used for "strict equality" or "identity" like it is often in other languages - some Ruby objects that implement it use it for "membership" tests, like in ranges (`(1..3) === 2 ==> true`) or regular expressions (`/el/ === "hello" ==> true` you can think of regular expressions as the group of all strings that would match), others implement it as equals.

So - how is the `if` working? Well, `if` and other "forced boolean contexts" check for "falsehood". In Ruby we recognize two false values - `false` and `nil`, everything else will run the truth branch of an `if`. This is actually the method `!` that you also used in your second example. This method is [implemented in `BasicObject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/BasicObject.html#method-i-21) to return true for all objects, except if the object's type is the type of `false` - [`FalseClass`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/FalseClass.html) or the type for `nil` - [`NilClass`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/NilClass.html), in which case it returns `true`.

So your examples actually mean:

1. Check for the truthiness of `""`. Because that value's type is neither `FalseClass` or `NilClass`, it is always true.
2. For the value `""`, call the method `!` - which will return `false` because the object is neither a `FalseClass` or a `NilClass` - then call `!` on the result, which will return `true` because `false` is a `FalseClass` instance.
3. For the value `""` call the method `===` with the argument `true`, but since it is an alias for `==` - call that instead (see 4).
4. For the value `""` call the method `==` with the argument `true`. `String`'s implementation of `==` will never return `true` for an argument that isn't a `String` type.

Comment: Just because many operators are implemented as methods doesn’t mean there are no operators in Ruby. Beside, not all operators are implemented as methods (variable assignment, logical, ternary, scope resolution).

Comment: @Stefan, yes, but hyperbole is sometimes important in order to pull the bandaid cleanly.

Answer (score 2):

The only falsy values in Ruby are `false` and `nil`. Everything else is "truthy," but not necessarily *equal* to `true`. This includes empty objects like a String, Hash, or Array.

Pragmatically, it might help to think of `==` as "comparably equivalent to" rather than "equals." For example:

```
1 == 1.0 #=> true
```

This is true even though one is an Integer and one is a Float because they are comparably equivalent in value, even if they aren't the same object or of the same type.

In the same way, `""` is truthy because it is not comparably equivalent to `false` or `nil`. However, it's also not the same object type as `true`, nor comparably equivalent to `true`. An empty String is simply "not falsy," which makes it truthy but not actually `true`.

Remember, only `false` and `nil` are falsy. Everything else, and I mean *everything*, is truthy even if it isn't strictly speaking `true`.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, the only "falsey types" are `FalseClass` and `NilClass`, which have the instances `false` and `nil` respectively. All other values are considered "truthy". This is possibly different to what you'd expect coming from other C-like values, in which we do things like this pretty freely:

```c
int x = get_value();
if (x) { /* implied x != 0 }
```

So, if you had something like this in Ruby:

```rb
puts 0 if 0     # => "0"
puts 1 if ""    # => "1"
puts 2 if []    # => "2"
puts 3 if false # => nil
puts 4 if true  # => "4"
puts 5 if nil   # => "5"
```

So, if `""` acts truthy, why isn't it equal to `true`? If that were how we defined `==`, then this would also need to resolve to `true` then, since both values are truthy:

```rb
"1" == "2"
```

The difference here is that `==` is asking if two things are the same, which `""` and `true` are most certainly not. Further, Ruby does not automatically convert types for you (like other languages like JavaScript do), so `""` does not automatically get converted to a boolean during its comparison.